# ASmack - Where to get ChatManager from?

Tags: android, asmack

I am trying to make a small XMPP-capable chat application for a school project using aSmack-8-4-rc2 on Android 4.2.2, and I am having issues getting a `ChatManager` object to process incoming messages.

Every example I have seen so far does

```
ChatManager manager = connection.getChatManager();
```

However, it seems that at some point during development, the function `getChatManager()` was either removed or replaced from class `XMPPConnection` (or `XMPPTCPConnection`, since the former seems to have been deprecated), and I am unable to find ANY documentation or examples that give me any indication of what replacements I can get.

I tried using constructors from the class `ChatManager`. It does appear to have a constructor, albeit a private one and I am therefore unable to create the object. I am assuming it is intended to be a singleton, but I have yet to find a way to get to it.

Does anybody know where was this function moved to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just found it. Leaving it here for future reference:

```
ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

Comment: Really useful! Is there any place where it is documented?

Comment: I was unable to find any documentation for this library. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: It's mentioned in the answer of Flow in this forum thread - https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/53199 . Can't get more official than this.